# How to implement Listner for particular task?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am implementing one app related to network .

Regarding my app

I am checking the network sate

```
private void isNetworkAvailable(Context con) {       
   ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);        
   networkstate = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();    
}


if(net work is available) {
    // execute
}
else // if network is not available
{
   // here i want to create a listener for checking for net work state every time.
}
```

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

> NetworkInfo.DetailedState or NetworkInfo.State

and use this method which reports the current fine-grained state of the network

> getDetailedState()

This method Report the extra information about the network state, if any was provided by the lower networking layers., if one is available.

> getExtraInfo()

if you want more information then [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html)